# ANTLR 4: How to generate a parse error from an embedded action?

Tags: error-handling, antlr, runtime-error, antlr4

I have written an ANTLR parser in Java that converts from one domain-specific language to another and uses embedded actions to generate intermediate structural information. During parsing these embedded actions use data loaded at run-time from an external file to validate the input being parsed. Thus it is possible for an input file that is correct according to the grammar to fail due to external requirements loaded at run-time.

A simple example of this kind of situation would be a parser in which a list of valid keywords comes from a text file supplied by the user. A keyword that would parse correctly according to the grammar may fail because it is not in the keyword list supplied by the user at run-time.

I can already catch these problems and bail out of parsing, but my error messages lose the context so it's difficult for the user to know where the error is occurring in the input.

Is there a way to have an ANTLR embedded action cause the parser to throw a fake parse exception that includes the current parse context? For example:

```
line 125:11 <my custom error message generated from embedded action goes here>
```

I have read through the ANTLR 4 Reference book but could not find any relevant examples.

Comment: Note: I realize that using an AST-traversal approach would be more flexible than using embedded actions, but I would appreciate answers specific to solving this problem in the non-AST context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found a solution:

```
Token startPos = getContext().getStart();
String inputLocation = "line " + startPos.getLine() + ":" + startPos.getCharPositionInLine();
```